# QuickSort, Using Median as Pivot. Not Sorting Correctly

Tags: java, quicksort, median

I'm trying to make my own quickSort method and am placing the pivot to be the median value among the first, middle, and last elements of the list. However, when I put some random numbers into an array and then use my quickSort method, they occasionally aren't sorted correctly. I was wondering what the bug in my code is and how I can fix it.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void quickSort(T[] list) {
      quickSort(list, 0, list.length-1);
 }

 public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void quickSort(T[] list, int first, int last) {
      int pivotIndex=0;
      if(last>first) {
            pivotIndex=partition(list,first,last, smartPivot);
            quickSort(list, first, pivotIndex-1, smartPivot);
            quickSort(list,pivotIndex+1, last, smartPivot);
       }
  }
  public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void swap(T[] list, int index, int index2) {
      T temp=list[index];
      list[index]=list[index2];
      list[index2]=temp;
 }

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T median(T[] list, int first, int last) {
      int pivotIndex=(first+last)/2;
      if (list[last].compareTo(list[first])<0) {
           swap(list,first,last);
      }

      else if(list[last].compareTo(list[pivotIndex])<0) {
           swap(list,pivotIndex,last);
      }

      else if (list[pivotIndex].compareTo(list[first])<0) {
           swap(list,first,pivotIndex);
      }

      swap(list,pivotIndex, last-1);
      return list[last-1];
 }

 public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int partition(T[] list, int first, int last) {


      T pivot=null;
      int low=first+1;
      int high=last;

       pivot=median(list,first,last);
           while(high>low) {
                while(low<=high && list[low].compareTo(pivot)<=0) {
                     low++;
                }
                while(low<=high && list[high].compareTo(pivot)>0) {
                     high--;
                }

                if(high>low) {
                     swap(list,high,low);
                }
           }

           while(high>first && list[high].compareTo(pivot)>=0) {
                high--;
           }
           return first;
      }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Integer[] x={34,34543,98,562,1,6456,0,9};

      quickSort(x,0,x.length-1);
      for(int j=0; j<x.length;j++) {
           System.out.print(x[j]+" ");
      }
```

}

Comment: Why does `median` move the pivot to the all-but-last element of the list?

Answer (score 0):

`partition` seems to assume that `median` will move the pivot to the front of the list (`low=first+1`), but it actually moves it to the not-quite end of the list.